# Linker Command Failed with exit code 1: duplicate symbol

Tags: duplicates, symbols

```
ld: duplicate symbol _velocityX in \
/Users/Student/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/finalproject-ffzevekmatxvhrgisgeleoijyllr/Build/Intermediates/finalproject.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/finalproject.build/Objects-normal/i386/Level2ViewController.o \
and \
/Users/Student/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/finalproject-ffzevekmatxvhrgisgeleoijyllr/Build/Intermediates/finalproject.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/finalproject.build/Objects-normal/i386/Level1ViewController.o \
for architecture i386
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

UPDATE: added \ + newlines for readability

I have no clue what is wrong with my project, can anyone help?

Comment: Well: the linker complains that the symbol "_velocityX" is defined in two objects: ".../Objects-normal/i386/Level2ViewController.o" and ".../Objects-normal/i386/Level1ViewController.o" Maybe you specified the object twice on the linker-invocation? Or you included a .C file? Or you have stale objects floating around?

Answer (score 23):

I had same problem. But it was my fault. :). You might have writen a `#import file.m` instead of `#import file.h`. So Compiles Resource will duplicate symbol file.o.
- That's it! ^^ To see it, You remove that error file, build --> Show error row --> then recopy it.

Comment: haha...how silly :)  thanks for this. i wouldn't have ever noticed this typo.

Answer (score 4):

I had this same error, it was because I defined a constant with the same name in two separate .m files. Once I changed the name in one of them, it compiled.

For example in my ViewController.m I had:

```
#import "ViewController.h"
const int IPHONE4 = 480;
```

and in my Menu.m:

```
#import "Menu.h"
const int IPHONE4 = 480;
```

I changed my Menu.m to:

```
#import "Menu.h"
const int IPHONE4H = 480;
```

Answer (score 2):

You probably have `double _velocityX` in a header file included by both `Level1ViewController.c` and `Level2ViewController.c`, when the header should have `extern double _velocityX`, and *exactly one* of the `.c` files should have `double _velocityX`. (Assuming the type of `_velocityX` is `double`, which seemed reasonable, and also assuming this is either C or C++ and not Fortran or something).

Answer (score 2):

I ran into this same error while trying to integrate a few frameworks into my app.

First I was using Sparrow - a graphics library, and by default I had a main.m file, things were fine until I tried to integrate Parse which also depended on the FacebookSDK.  Within the FacebookSDK folders there is a Sample app called Scrumptious with a main.m as well which was the source of my problems.  I removed the sample apps directory and everything built fine.