# Linker Command Failed with Exit Code 1 - Duplicate Symbols

Tags: objective-c, xcode, linker

I am trying to run and test my app in Xcode 8.2.1, but I am getting this error.  I've been searching around, but cannot find an answer that works for my problem.  What could be the culprit here?

> duplicate symbol _randomPositionY in:
>       /Users/tetadickens/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Stealth_Crash-gbxbrdfgfsyxnkafhbmltuvxvsvz/Build/Intermediates/Stealth Crash.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Stealth Crash.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/ViewController.o
>       /Users/tetadickens/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Stealth_Crash-gbxbrdfgfsyxnkafhbmltuvxvsvz/Build/Intermediates/Stealth Crash.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Stealth Crash.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/AppDelegate.o
>   duplicate symbol _Y in:
>       /Users/tetadickens/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Stealth_Crash-gbxbrdfgfsyxnkafhbmltuvxvsvz/Build/Intermediates/Stealth Crash.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Stealth Crash.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/ViewController.o
>       /Users/tetadickens/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Stealth_Crash-gbxbrdfgfsyxnkafhbmltuvxvsvz/Build/Intermediates/Stealth Crash.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Stealth Crash.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/AppDelegate.o
>   duplicate symbol _randomPositionX in:
>       /Users/tetadickens/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Stealth_Crash-gbxbrdfgfsyxnkafhbmltuvxvsvz/Build/Intermediates/Stealth Crash.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Stealth Crash.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/ViewController.o
>       /Users/tetadickens/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Stealth_Crash-gbxbrdfgfsyxnkafhbmltuvxvsvz/Build/Intermediates/Stealth Crash.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Stealth Crash.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/AppDelegate.o
>   ld: 27 duplicate symbols for architecture x86_64
>   clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

EDIT

This issue started after I went to Editor > Validate Settings.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Linker Command Failed with exit code 1: duplicate symbol](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11727444/linker-command-failed-with-exit-code-1-duplicate-symbol)

Answer (score 0):

As the compiler has said, there are multiple definitions of the `randomPositionY` in your code. It is okay if you declare the function in a header file but you may not have multiple implementations of a function. After all, how can the compiler know which implementation should be executed when the function is called?

Answer (score 0):

There are 27 duplicate symbol found in your code,  randomposition_y, randomposition_x, symbol_y etc. 
My guess by showing your error that you use these variables in appdelegate and in your viewcontroller. Rename these variables will solve your error.